# npm install command not working in npm script

Tags: npm, npm-install, git-bash, npm-scripts, npm-start

Given a `package.json` that includes the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm install && webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors",
  "build": "npm install && webpack --env.prod --progress --colors",
  "start": "npm run dev"
}
```

Running `npm start` gives me many errors of the sort

```
`npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\repos\my-project\node_modules\.staging\core-js-ea8988d1\client\shim.js'
```

followed by

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 21: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
```

However, if instead I just run `npm install` directly, the npm installation of packages succeeds with no errors, and then I can run `npm start` thereafter with no issues. Why is this? There seems to be some kind of issue with including `npm install` in an npm script if the packages are not yet installed. I also tried setting `start` to `"npm install"` but running `npm start` gave me the same errors in that case.